# How to replace the deprecated tex2D(texture<T, 2, cudaReadModeElementType>, float, float) [with T=float]?

Tags: cuda

In a cuda 11.3 program, I'm using

```
tex2D(texture<T, 2, cudaReadModeElementType>, float, float)
```

which was declared deprecated in texture_fetch_functions.h(198). What replaces it ? and how do I use it ?

> warning : function "tex2D(texture<T, 2, cudaReadModeElementType>,
> float, float) [with T=float]" 2>C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
> Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\include\texture_fetch_functions.h(198): here was
> declared deprecated

Comment: You could consult the documentation which explains the texture reference API deprecation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Textures](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#texture-functions) have historically come in 2 usage models: texture references and [texture objects](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-kepler-texture-objects-improve-performance-and-flexibility/).  Texture references were the "original" mechanism supplied with CUDA and texture objects were introduced with the Kepler generation of GPUs.

Texture reference usage is being deprecated in CUDA 11.3.  Nearly anything you can do with texture references can be done with texture objects, with some refactoring.

The replacement API for the one you indicate is documented [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#tex2d-object).  There are many questions here on the `cuda` tag discussing both texture reference usage and texture object usage, and this [introductory blog](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-kepler-texture-objects-improve-performance-and-flexibility/) covers the benefits of refactoring to use texture objects.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54098747/cuda-how-to-create-2d-texture-object/54100165#54100165) is a complete worked example of using `tex2D()` for texture objects.