# What's the replacement for cuModuleGetSurfRef and cuModuleGetTexRef?

Tags: cuda, textures, surface, cuda-driver

CUDA 12 indicates that these two functions:

```
CUresult cuModuleGetSurfRef (CUsurfref* pSurfRef, CUmodule hmod, const char* name);
CUresult cuModuleGetTexRef (CUtexref* pTexRef, CUmodule hmod, const char* name);
```

which obtain a reference to surface or a texture, respectively, from a loaded module - are deprecated.

What are they deprecated in favor of? Are surfaces and textures in modules to be accessed differently? Will they be entirely out of modules? If it's the latter, how would one work with them using the CUDA driver API?

Comment: There is no replacement. Texture and surface references are being removed from CUDA in favour of objects

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/67193791/681865

Answer (score 1):

So, based on @talonmies' comment, it seems the "replacement" are ["texture objects"](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__TEXOBJECT.html#group__CUDA__TEXOBJECT) and ["surface objects"](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__SURFOBJECT.html#group__CUDA__SURFOBJECT). The main difference - as far as is evident in the API - is that the new "objects" have less API calls, which take richer descriptors. Thus, the user sets fields themselves, and does not need the large number of `cuTexRefGetXXXX` and `cuTexRefSetXXXX` calls. There are also ["tensor map objects"](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__TENSOR__MEMORY.html#group__CUDA__TENSOR__MEMORY), appearing with Compute Capability 9.0 and later.